# My textarea value would not enter the database

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

iam trying to get the bio of my experts from a form in my add.blade but the only data retrieved is name... i tried emptying the value inside the textarea and giving a value="{{ old('bio')" }} still does not work. heres the latest code..

add.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('creato') }}">
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <div class="form-group ">
                  <b><label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label></b>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                </div>
                <div>
                ------------
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <b><label class="control-label" for="bio">A little about the expert</label></b>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
      {{-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM THIS TEXT AREA HERE DOES NOT SEND VALUE --}}
                  <textarea type="text" class="kokoa" id="bio" name="bio"> {{ old('bio') }} </textarea> 
                </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
            <hr>
            <a href="{{ route('home') }}">Back</a>
            </form>
```

routes.php

```
Route::group(['prefix'  => 'experts'], function () 
{

Route::get('/add',['as'=>'add','uses'=>'ExpertsController@add']);

Route::post('/wee',['as'=>'creato','uses'=>'ExpertsController@create']);});
```

ExpertsController.php

```
public function add(){
    $title = 'A new expert is born';
    return view('add',compact('title'));

}


  public function create(CreateExpertsRequest $request) {
    $experts = Experts::create([
        'name'=>$request->get('name'),
        'bio'=>$request->get('bio')
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

CreatesExpertsRequest

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'bio' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Share your Experts model

Comment: OMG how could i miss that thx  Gaurav Dave this was my model previously..
class Experts extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'experts';
    protected $fillable = [
   'name',
   ];
}

Answer (score 0):

i didnt place it fillable in my model...

expert.php (previous)

```
    class Experts extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'experts';
    protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            ];
}
```

now

```
    class Experts extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'experts';
    protected $fillable = [
            'name','bio'


    ];
```

}